# Unable to export contact flow in Amazon Connect due to large size

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, export, amazon-connect

Hi I have created a contact flow in amazon connect and its complex. There are above 100 blocks (prompts, customer inputs invoke lambda etc) and when i try to export the contact flow (i want to import it in different test environment), it gives the following error

"Failed to export contact flow. The number of blocks or resources in the flow exceeds the maximum allowed or the file exceeds 1MB"

I tried to remove the blocks and i am able to export but after certain limit (102 blocks in this case), i am unable to export it.

Any suggestions? can we pass data from one contact flow to another?

Answer (score 0):

You should not build flows with that many blocks, instead break your flows up into smaller modular flows that are chained together. You can transfer between Contact flows using the “transfer to flow” block. See block definitions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/userguide/contactflow.html#contact-blocks)

Attribute data is scoped to the contact, not the flow, so it will persist across all Contact flows that are processed during the contacts life.

Breaking your flows into smaller chunks, with less blocks per flow, will also allow the editor to remain responsive.